# LibreOffice Resolution Problem

Tags: libreoffice, 13.04

This morning I upgraded to 13.04 from 12.10. Everything seemed to be working fine until I checked LibreOffice and something had gone funny with the visuals (and Gnome integration? My knowledge of Ubuntu is pretty limited).

The problem is the extra 'border' around the top and right side, which basically bugs the hell out (including the scrollbar, not visible below), showing whatever was on that part of the screen when LibreOffice was opened and stopping the window maximising properly. Resolution is 1024x600 (Acer Aspire One notebook).

I can try to answer any further questions, quite hard to accurately describe the problem.

[image]

Comment: Also, have purged and reinstalled libreoffice with no change

Comment: Did you install from a download, a PPA or from the software center? For a download from LibreOffice, it may be fixed by downloading and installing the Desktop Integration package.

Comment: Have tried installing it from all three (also adding the desktop-integration for dpkg install). Interestingly the minimum requirements on the site say 1024x768 but it ran no problems before I upgraded to 13.04

Comment: Do you have the libreoffice-gnome, libreoffice-gtk, and libreoffice-gtk3 packages installed? I'm not sure about that weird space, but it the toolbars look like they do when those packages aren't present.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836151&highlight=13.04%20ubuntu%20libreoffice%204.0%20display%20bug%20dialog).

Installing `libreoffice-gtk` with Synaptic Package Manager and restarting LibreOffice solved the problem for me.